# Can't understand the PCL sample point clouds(.pcd) without header

Tags: computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am working with point clouds and using PCL. I read about the .pcd file format from:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php

The above link mentions that every .pcd file contains a header and yet I have come across many .pcd files that have no header. Yet the pcl reader is able to read the file correctly. But i can't make sense of the fields in the file without header. For example, have a look at this file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqQoK.jpg
I know the first 3 fields represent xyz cooridnates but what are the other five fields.

Comment: You should try looking at the source code of the pcl reader you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .pcd format can be formatted in ASCII or binary. You're looking at a binary version. The header is human-readable in the ASCII format but obviously not in the binary format. The `pcl::PCDReader` and `pcl::PCDWriter` are capable of reading or writing both types. The advantage of the binary type is small file sizes, whereas the advantage of the ASCII type is it's human-readable.